# How to push to Github from C9?

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

I linked my Github account to C9 and cloned a private repository. Then I made some changes to the files and uploaded a couple of folders through the IDE, and in the end used `git push` in the terminal in C9. This caused the changes in the files to update, but the new folders that I had uploaded and the files in them are not there.

Comment: This sounds to me like you perhaps never added the new folders in question before pushing (I just made this mistake about 5 minutes ago).  Can you give us more information?

Comment: I cloned anukul.github.io 's repository to C9 and it now looks like https://anukulgithubio-anukul.c9.io/. But the changes do not reflect in the Github repository.

Comment: You need to tell us precisely which Git commands you ran so that we know what your status is.  The above comment does not do this.

Comment: I ran `git commit -am "your message goes here"` and `git push`. My above comment was to show you that I have uploaded the folders because their contents show up in the C9 repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told us that:

> and in the end used git push in the terminal in C9. This caused the changes in the files to update, but the new folders that I had uploaded and the files in them are not there.

You may have done a `git push` to the repository, but this would not send any files/folders new or old which were not *staged*.  To see where you stand locally, type `git status` from the Git console.  My guess is that you will see the folders which never seemed to make it to the repository under the `"Changes not staged for commit"` section.  To fix this, you can do `git add` on the files and folders, and then push again.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to the command line way of using github. `git add` was what I was missing.

Comment: You'll find that this is a perennial problem which happens, even among seasoned Git users.  This is especially true with new files, which actually start off life as completely untracked.  Happy to help you out.